# Change the screen size and dpi

Tags: screen

Is there a way to make Android think it has a different screen size and dpi than what was programmed in its factory settings?

I'm asking because we bought a 7-inch tablet recently, and its interface is too large for a 7-inch tablet. I installed [System Info Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sysinfodroid) and it confirmed what I suspected: The tablet thinks its screen is 4.86 inches with 192dpi.

Is there a way to fix this and tell it its screen is 7 inches and 133dpi?

The tablet is Genx GX7-3GS running Android 4.2.2.

Comment: There are several apps dealing with DPI settings (for some examples, be welcome to my list on [Display Settings Apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_541)). But to *change* density, you will need root access.

Answer (score 1):

You can change. First ROOT your device. 
Using file manager go to your root directory. Open folder named `system`. In that open file named `build.prop` using text editor. 
Search for option called `lcd_display=` (after equals to enter your default DPI value) and save file.
Now reboot. Done.