# Make website think you have a different size screen

Tags: applications, wi-fi, screen, browser

## If you really want a desktop version of a website to load you need it to think you have a desktop size screen.

## The resolution of your screen is irrelevant

> I've been told that changing the user agent isn't enough.
>
> I've been told asking for desktop version does not work 90% of the
> time.

**The website measures the actual size of the screen.** **It does not care about DPI.**

So, this  [Change the screen size and dpi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81561/change-the-screen-size-and-dpi) does not answer this question.

How do you change the screen size in android. Or trick it.
I'm open to any suggestions. I would like a rooted and unrooted method if possible. I don't mind downloading 3rd party applications either to get this to work.

End goal is to get desktop website to load.

Comment: How so? It's not like phone / tablet / PC resolutions are far apart these days.

Comment: @AndyYan **It has nothing to do with resolution. It has to do with screen size.** The website is measuring your screen in inches. Or I guess millimeters if you are in smarter parts of the world. I added that to my question to make it more clear